# Difference between two queries

Tags: sql

Is there any difference between these two queries?

Query 1:

```
select a.idclientecrm from clientescrmporlistadeclientescrm a
inner join clientescrmporlistadeclientescrm b on (a.idclientecrm=b.idclientecrm and            a.idlistadeclientescrm = 58)
inner join tareas c on b.idclientecrm = c.idclientecrm
where b.idlistadeclientescrm = 70
```

Query 2:

```
select a.idclientecrm from clientescrmporlistadeclientescrm a
inner join clientescrmporlistadeclientescrm b on (a.idclientecrm=b.idclientecrm and   a.idlistadeclientescrm = 58)
where b.idlistadeclientescrm = 70
```

I know the first one has the extra inner join on the "tareas" table, but I didn't know it would give me a different result. Can anyone tell me why?

Edit:

I'm trying to join the result of this query:

```
select a.idclientecrm from clientescrmporlistadeclientescrm a
inner join clientescrmporlistadeclientescrm b on (a.idclientecrm=b.idclientecrm and   a.idlistadeclientescrm = 58)
where b.idlistadeclientescrm = 70
```

with another table called "tareas", from which I only need the max date. There can be more than one date for each idclientecrm. The "tareas" table has the idclientecrm field to join tables.

Hope it's understandable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because the additional inner join is an additional constraint.  It will only return records where b and c's idclientecrm matches.

Comment: Because the point of an inner join is to filter rows based on a relation between two tables. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join

Comment: So ... you're asking why, when you use two different queries on the same data, you get different results?

Comment: @scottb: It's not an entirely unreasonable question; different queries can have the same result set.

Comment: Exactly but the first one is giving me more rows than the other one. I forgot to tell that.

Comment: People downvoting questions because they are ''novice'' and may sound dumb actually erode the very reason S.O was created. I might be wrong though

Comment: @Nicholas Kyriakides: the reason why I'm asking is exactly because I'm a novice, but I should have clarified that at the beginning of the post. Thnx for understanding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that the queries would have the same results is if the `tareas` join matched every record (in the preceding from..inner join set) *exactly once*.

If the first query results in *more* rows, then the `tareas` contains duplicates records per the join predicate (i.e. it has duplicate `idclientecrm` values). This why the records must be matched *exactly once* for the same result set. (If this was meant to be a 1-1 relationship then some constraints were not setup correctly .. whoops!)

Consider this simple [inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join) example showing the outcome with different multiplicities:

```
A <- { 1, 2, 4 }
B <- { 1, 2(#1), 2(#2), 3 }

A join B => { 1, 2(#1), 2(#2) }
```

Reason for result:

- A.1 match B.1 - this is the only record that matched *exactly once*
- A.2 match B.2(#1)
- A.2 match B.2(#2)
- A.4 no match
- B.3 no match

I think that this excerpt from Wikipedia explains the concept well:

> The result of the join can be defined as the outcome of *first taking the Cartesian product (or Cross join) of all records* in the tables (combining every record in table A with every record in table B)—then *return all records which satisfy the join predicate*.

(This why a CROSS JOIN with a WHERE can return the same results as an INNER JOIN - ick, though!)

Comment: excellent example. Helped me understand very clearly the difference. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

An inner join means: for each row in the left-hand table, return all matching rows in the right-hand table.  Do not return rows without a match in the right-hand table.

So joining a new table can both reduce and increase the number of rows returned:

- Reduce because the new join filters out rows without a match
- Increase because the new join can add more than one row per row in the left-hand table.  That will occur if more than one right-hand row matches a left-hand one.

Comment: It could raise and lower leaving a net-gain of unknown :D